# Whitelisting a URL in AWS WAF webACL rules

Tags: amazon-waf

Is it possible to whitelist a url to my rate limiting web ACL rule in AWS WAF? If so, could I have some example for that?

This is what I have currently but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
{
  "Name": "<some-name>",
  "Priority": 0,
  "Statement": {
    "RateBasedStatement": {
      "Limit": 100,
      "EvaluationWindowSec": 300,
      "AggregateKeyType": "IP",
      "ScopeDownStatement": {
        "NotStatement": {
          "Statement": {
            "ByteMatchStatement": {
              "SearchString": "https://myurl.com",
              "FieldToMatch": {
                "UriPath": {}
              },
              "TextTransformations": [
                {
                  "Priority": 0,
                  "Type": "NONE"
                }
              ],
              "PositionalConstraint": "EXACTLY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Action": {
    "Block": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "<my-metric>"
  }
}
```

I've seen some other similar questions but they seem to be for whitelisting a certain path or IP